# How to consuming SOAP XML from jquery using jquery SOAP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xml, soap

I'm trying connect my app to a SOAP web service XML, uso jquery SOAP (https://github.com/doedje/jquery.soap). The connection worked but I don't obtain data.

I attach my code (url, user and password are examples), Help me please.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="app/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/jquery.soap.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <pre><code id="salida">...</code></pre>
</body>

<script>
    $.soap({
        url: 'http://myservice.com/sisWSAFI/Service.asmx',
        method: 'GetSession',

        data: {
            user: 'user',
            password: 'pass'
        },

        success: function(soapResponse) {
            var respuesta = soapResponse.toString();
            console.log(respuesta.GetSession);
        },
        error: function(SOAPResponse) {
            // show error
        }
    });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Check the console for errors.

Comment: "The connection worked" Based on what?

Comment: No, the console doesn't show errors.